# Flex 3.6, Air 2.0 and URLRequestDefaults.idleTimeout

Tags: apache-flex, air, httprequest

I've a big problem with my flex framework.

So far, i ran my application in a `Air 1.5` runtime.

Lately, i had to migrate to `Air 2.0` cause `HTTPService` gzip support.

Unfortunally, run my app with a `Air 2.0 runtime`, make my `HTTP requests` last no more than `30 seconds`, then a `timeout error` is triggered. This is absolutely too low for my application as some request can last even 60 minutes.

I searched a solution and i've found that setting `URLRequestDefaults.idleTimeout` to a very high value can override the 30 seconds limit.

Unfortunally the latter property is not found in my `Flex 3.6` environment and i can't find a workaround =((

Someone here have any idea about how to get rid of it?

Thank you

Comment: URLrequestDefaults,idleTimeout has been available since AIR 1.0 and is part of the native Flash Player API, not part of the Flex SDK, so Flex version shouldnt affect it. Is your IDE not recognising it (ie not adding suitable import)?

Comment: idleTimeout is supported from Air 2.0 as [this reference page](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequestDefaults.html) claims

Comment: anyway... i don't use any IDE. Just exec mxmlc (bundled in flex 3.6 flex sdk) in a shell environment. Unfortunally it couldn't find the idleTimeout property whilst if i use the 4.6 sdk the latter property is found.

Comment: good spot on being AIR 2.0 - i was looking at the class def, not the specific property

Comment: can you post your build script?

Comment: i resolved removing the -strict option from the compiler command line =\

Answer (score 0):

```
import flash.net.URLRequestDefaults;

URLRequestDefaults.idleTimeout = 30000;
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.